# How to hide windows 7 license information

Tags: windows-7, license

Can I hide Windows 7 Enterprise license information from my screen?

Screenshot: 
[image]

Comment: What do you mean from my screen ? Is it on your desktop ?

Comment: Yes, at right-bottom

Comment: @DavidZIP - An actual Windows 7 license does not expired after 47 days. I highly suspect that message is because your running a Windows 7 Enterprise trial license. If you want to get rid of that information activate a Windows 7 license.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Command-line.

Disabled version and build number of Windows does not appear on the desktop:

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v PaintDesktopVersion /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

Enabled version and build number of Windows appears on the desktop:

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v PaintDesktopVersion /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

Logoff:

```
shutdown /l
```

way 2 - edit `shell32.dll.mui`

[Show Your Desired Text on Desktop by Customizing Windows Vista & 7 Watermark (Build Number Info)](http://www.askvg.com/show-your-desired-text-on-desktop-by-customizing-windows-vista-build-number/)

Comment: While this does indeed get rid of the text, in the author's case, its because of an invalid license.

Comment: @Ramhound The question is not about blocking mechanisms licenses and block the response or the transfer of the trial period. It more a question of presentation. And after the expiration of the trial period will be writing about that period is over. I think that the mechanism with unobtrusive reminders significantly contributed to the purchase of these already popular operating systems.

Comment: This simple hides the fact the license is invalid it does not solve the underline problem the author has, unless of course, the screenshot is simply a generic screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Activate your license and that message should go away. Just go to the start button and search for "Activate Windows"

[image]